# How do I add custom css to a DataTable with a bokeh server application?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to be able to add a CSS class to a Bokeh DataTable in a Bokeh server application and write the CSS externally. How can I do this?

From what I've read I though I would be able to add css_classes like the following.

```
data_table = DataTable(source=in_src, fit_columns=True, columns=columns, width=820, height=300, index_position=None, editable=False, selectable=True, css_classes=["hidden_table"])
```

Then in an external file using CSS do something like this.

```
.hidden_table {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I was expecting to see the DataTable hidden in the output but it is still showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone else. This issue was caused by a bug in version 1.0.2. I upgraded to 1.2.0 and the code ran as expected. When you upgrade, make sure to upgrade your JavaScript files as well or you'll have a version mismatch issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [directory format](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format), then you can include the css file in the `index.html` template file. If you use single module format, then add the css to a DIV component. Here is an example that change the font-weight of the table to bold.

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import Column
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, Div

data = dict(
        dates=[date(2014, 3, i+1) for i in range(10)],
        downloads=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
    )
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date", formatter=DateFormatter()),
        TableColumn(field="downloads", title="Downloads"),
    ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280, css_classes=["my_table"])
style = Div(text="""
<style>
.my_table{
font-weight:bold !important;
}
</style>
""")
curdoc().add_root(Column(data_table, style))
```

Comment: Yes! It turns out there was a bug in ther version of Bokeh I was using. Upgrading fixed the issue for me. Thank You for your response.